# javascript to change all class values in a div

Tags: javascript, classname

Is there a way to change the class value for all of the buttons with JS? right now I've got:

```
  var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName("yui-button yui-radio-button");
```

and then a for loop

```
  for (i=0;i<nodes.length;i++) {
     nodes[i].className = "something";
  }
```

is there anyway to bypass the for loop and change all the class values?

Here's the html:

```
    <div id="season" align="center">
     <div id="seasonButtons" class="yui-buttongroup">
      <span id="yui-gen0" class="yui-button yui-radio-button">
       <span class="first-child">
        <button type="button" id="yui-gen0-button">Spring</button>
       </span>
      </span>
      <span id="yui-gen1" class="yui-button yui-radio-button">
       <span class="first-child">
        <button type="button" id="yui-gen1-button">Summer</button>
       </span>
      </span>
      <span id="yui-gen2" class="yui-button yui-radio-button">
       <span class="first-child">
        <button type="button" id="yui-gen2-button">Fall</button>
       </span>
      </span>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I am not sure about it: but try it: $('.yui-button.yui-radio-button').attr('class', 'newclass');

Comment: You could use jQuery for more concise code: $(".yui-button .yui-radio-button").prop("class", "something");

Comment: If you are using javascript, then you can't bypass looping. Using jquery, you can bypass the looping statement

Comment: But, presumably the loop just happens in the jquery code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this with jquery

```
    $(".yui-button,.yui-radio-button").addClass("something").removeClass("yui-button yui-radio-button");
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're just using plain javascript, then you need some kind of loop in order to change multiple nodes in the array.

You could write yourself a helper function that would operate on all the nodes in the array, but somewhere there's a loop that's going to run.

Since it looks like you're using YUI, YUI probably has ways of operating on a collection of nodes with one call.

Answer (score 0):

Add a common class to all div. for example class="common"

then

$('.common').addClass('newClassName');

Answer (score 0):

**NodeList getElementsByClassName(string classNames):**

Returns an array-like object of elements that have a class attribute that includes all of the specificied classNames.classNames.

If you want to work with javascript, you´ll need a loop to change the attributes of that nodes.